# Android: Drag and Drop multiple images

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I have this "Drag and Drop" thingy.

So basically we are making a prototype to let the user (kid) to drag and drop the candy to a jar.
The code below will works only for one candy (1 image), the second image will not move at all. I don't know why.

Any answer will be highly appreciated and I hope you can explain it because I am really new in this android development. Thank you.

These are the code I have been researching for a while

```
package com.example.mathventure;

import com.example.mathventure.R.drawable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class AddTutActivity extends Activity {
    private static int candyInJar = 3;
    private int candyOutJar = 2;
    private int totalCandy;
    //private String candyId;
    private ImageView[] candies = new ImageView[11];
    private ImageView[] candiesOut = new ImageView[candyOutJar];
    private AbsoluteLayout tutLayout;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_tut);

        tutLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.tutLayout);
        tutLayout.setOnTouchListener(new touchListener());
        candiesOut[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.candyOut1);
        candiesOut[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.candyOut2);
        candiesOut[0].setOnTouchListener(new touchListener());
        candiesOut[1].setOnTouchListener(new touchListener());




        totalCandy = candyInJar + candyOutJar;
        for(int i=0;i<candies.length;i++){
            candies[i] = new ImageView(this);
        }
        candies[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_0);
        candies[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_1);
        candies[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_2);
        candies[3].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_3);
        candies[4].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_4);
        candies[5].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_5);
        candies[6].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_6);
        candies[7].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_7);
        candies[8].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_8);
        candies[9].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_9);
        candies[10].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.candy_jar_10);

        candies[candyInJar] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.candyInJar);

    }

    private boolean dragging = false;
    private Rect hitRect = new Rect();


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_add_tut, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class touchListener extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean eventConsumed = true;
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            int dragging = 0;
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (v == candiesOut[0]) {
                    dragging = 0;
                    eventConsumed = false;
                }
                if (v == candiesOut[1]){
                    dragging = 1;
                    eventConsumed = false;
                }
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (dragging == 0) {
                    candies[candyInJar].getHitRect(hitRect);
                    if (hitRect.contains(x, y)){
                        candiesOut[0].setImageDrawable(null);
                        candies[candyInJar].setImageResource(drawable.candy_jar_4);
                    }
                }
                else if(dragging == 1){
                    candies[candyInJar].getHitRect(hitRect);
                    if (hitRect.contains(x, y)){
                        candiesOut[1].setImageDrawable(null);
                        candies[candyInJar].setImageResource(drawable.candy_jar_5);
                    }
                }
                eventConsumed = false;

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (v != candiesOut[0] && v != candiesOut[1]) {
                    if (dragging != 1) {
                        setAbsoluteLocationCentered(candiesOut[dragging], x, y);
                    }
                }
            }

            return eventConsumed;
        }


        private void setAbsoluteLocationCentered(View v, int x, int y) {
            setAbsoluteLocation(v, x - v.getWidth() / 2, y - v.getHeight() / 2);
        }


        private void setAbsoluteLocation(View v, int x, int y) {
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            alp.x = x;
            alp.y = y;
            v.setLayoutParams(alp);
        }

        private void setSameAbsoluteLocation(View v1, View v2) {
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp2 = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v2.getLayoutParams();
            setAbsoluteLocation(v1, alp2.x, alp2.y);
        }
    }


}
```

this one is for the xml:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddTutActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/tutLayout">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:fontFamily="123Marker"
    android:text="3 candies + 2 candies = ?"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="123Marker"
    android:text="Below is a sample question on addition. Now, you need to move the 2 candies you wanted to add into the candy jar."
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
    android:background="#FF3300"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/candyInJar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="178dp"
    android:layout_x="149dp"
    android:layout_y="167dp"
    android:src="@drawable/candy_jar_3" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/candyOut1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="94dp"
    android:layout_x="489dp"
    android:layout_y="347dp"
    android:src="@drawable/candy" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/candyOut2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="544dp"
    android:layout_y="346dp"
    android:src="@drawable/candy" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend that you learn more about Android or you will have constant frustration.  Start by working out why this line is wrong, `class touchListener extends Activity implements OnTouchListener`, it should not extend Activity.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for your answer. I am aware about that OnTouchListener thingy. If you see the code, I did implements OnTouchListener in an inner class at the end of the code. The problem I had now is that I can only move one image and I need to move around 5 images. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but it sounds like "I can't be bothered to learn how to do this properly, somebody just fix my code.  There are multiple problems and unless you learn the basics, how do you expect to complete an app?  Another example, what does this line do?  `candiesOut[1].setOnTouchListener(new touchListener())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out this library and example;
https://github.com/2dwarfs/MultiTouchControllerTutorial

It will get you going with creating an image which is draggable and pinchable and you can add as many as you like as simple as adding a Drawable.

You could use this as is, adjust it to only be draggable, or take some lessons and inspiration from it.